# Working with strings in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, string

I have to create a class in Visual Basic called StringWork.

```
Public Class StringWork
```

Now i wrote a shared function in the class called Working that can take a string or a string and Boolean.

```
Public Shared Function Working(ByVal SingleString as string, optional BValu  as Boolean = true)as string
    if(working(SingleString))then
    'The handling of the string
    else if (working(SingleValue, BValue) then
    'do something else with string 
    end if
end function
```

The function I wrote is returning a string.
Can I access the string passed and edit characters in the string or change the position of characters?

Comment: Does it matter if a Boolean was passed or just needs to work differently based on it's value?

Comment: @Kevin Mangold It just needs to work differently based on the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use that optional parameter to determine how you handle that string:

```
Public Shared Function Working(ByVal singleString as string, _
                               Optional bValue as Boolean = True) As String
  If bValue Then
    'Handle the true part manipulating the result string
  Else
    'Handle the false part manipulating the result string
  End If

End Function
```

If you call this function like this:

```
Dim test As String = StringWork.Working("I am Spartacus")
```

it will call that Working function with bValue = true.

What bValue is suppose to represent isn't very clear from the code nor the post.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, and other .NET languages, strings are immutable. Typically, if you need to modify a string that is passed to your method, you would return the modified string. If however, you need it to modify the parameter, you can specify that it is a "ByRef" argument, in which case you will be able to set it to point to a new string object which will affect the variable that was passed into the method as a parameter.  If you need a truly mutable string, you will need a character array or a StringBuilder object.